# Using express server as electron app proxy for HTTPS requests

Tags: node.js, express, electron

I'm using session.setProxy to route every request through my basic express server.

I want to load a webpage and replace the page content with my own content.

If I load a http url the content from the express server is loaded but if I use https the app is just blank.

Here's the main.js of my electron app:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const { app, BrowserWindow } = electron
var win;

app.on('ready', initwindow);

function initwindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({show:true});

    win.webContents.session.setProxy({
        proxyRules: 'https://xxx',
    }, () => {
        win.loadURL('https://www.google.com/');
    });
}
```

Here's my express server:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const credentials = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx/fullchain.pem'),
};

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello world')
})

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpServer.listen(80, () => {
    console.log('HTTP Server running on port 80');
});

httpsServer.listen(443, () => {
    console.log('HTTPS Server running on port 443');
});
```

For example, if I use `win.loadURL('http://www.google.com/');` "Hello world" is displayed, but if I use `win.loadURL('https://www.google.com/');` the electron app is just white.

Is there something missing from my server or is what i'm trying to do no possible?

Comment: Did you succeed with this issue? I'm facing something similar and I have no idea how to deal with it